# Appending object key values to <li>

Tags: javascript, html, object, for-loop

Update: I edited the li's with classes to make it easier to understand and grab.

I did a fairly thorough search and could not find exactly what I was looking for. I have in my HTML a series of drop-down select boxes, currently populated with nothing.

```
<li class="games-owned">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>What Game Do You Want To Trade?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="games-wanted">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>What Game Would You Like To Have?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="city">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>What City Do You Live In?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
```

I need to populate them with the contents of a key value pair from my main.js mockData, here:

```
var mockData = {
"profile": [{
    "name": "Mario",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "California",
    "gameOwned": "Grand Theft Auto 5 (PS4)",
    "gameWanted": "Battlefield 4 (PS4)",
    "publishedAt": new Date()
}, {
    "name": "Colin",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "California",
    "gameOwned": "Battlefield 4 (PS4)",
    "gameWanted": "Grand Theft Auto 5 (PS4)",
    "publishedAt": new Date()
}],
"city": ["Los Angeles", "New York"],
    "game": ["Battlefield 4 (PS4)", "Grand Theft Auto 5 (PS4)"]
}
```

specifically the first two li's need to cull from "game" and the final li needs to cull from "city". Obviously, the process will be roughly the same for all three.

I've tried using a for loop but I'm not sure what should be connecting or what or how to get it connected in the first place. I'm relatively new. Suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: It would be a good idea to attempt something before you ask.

Comment: Are you trying to insert elements from your `mockData` collection into the three select elements. If so, which pieces of data do you wish to display and which do you desire to be the value for each of the new options? Do you plan to stuff all the data for each item into the option (either visibly or invisibly) or do you wish to establish at a later time which piece of data corresponds to any given selection?

Comment: I am trying to take each item in the mockData.game array and append each as its own option in the ```games-wanted``` and ```games-owned``` li. I want to do the same for the mockData.city array items and append them to the ```city``` li.

Comment: So on my first attempt I wasn't understanding what you were doing with the profile data - so the 2nd attempt ended up being a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is:

```js
var mockData = {
  "profile": [{
    "name": "Mario",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "California",
    "gameOwned": "Grand Theft Auto 5 (PS4)",
    "gameWanted": "Battlefield 4 (PS4)",
    "publishedAt": new Date()
  }, {
    "name": "Colin",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "California",
    "gameOwned": "Battlefield 4 (PS4)",
    "gameWanted": "Grand Theft Auto 5 (PS4)",
    "publishedAt": new Date()
  }],
  "city": ["Los Angeles", "New York"],
  "game": ["Battlefield 4 (PS4)", "Grand Theft Auto 5 (PS4)"]
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
 mockData.game.forEach(function(value, index) {
    document.querySelectorAll('li:nth-child(1) select')[0].innerHTML += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
    document.querySelectorAll('li:nth-child(2) select')[0].innerHTML += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
 });
 mockData.city.forEach(function(value, index) {
    document.querySelectorAll('li:nth-child(3) select')[0].innerHTML += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
  });
});
```

```html
<li>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>What Game Do You Want To Trade?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>What Game Would You Like To Have?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>What City Do You Live In?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: jQuery is not tagged.

Comment: @RobertParham I translate it in pure javascript in a while. Give me one second. Could you remove downvote?

Comment: @RobertParham Take a look now. I'm correct. If you now say no, I have no problem to remove my answer. It's not perfect. Thank you so much for your comment.

Comment: @RobertParham Thanks again.

Comment: @gaetanoM, wow thanks. Works like a charm. There's a lot here I don't understand and I've never seen before. I'm gonna look into the documentation for this.

Comment: @ColinAulds Try to google with: mdn javascript addEventListener. MDN is the mozilla documentation.

Comment: Not sure that hard coding indexes into the DOM is that good of an idea.  If he reorders or adds a new `li` this will suddenly produce incorrect results - it'll perhaps be considerably harder to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fvxm0tvd/

Add an ID to your selects so you can access them, do a standard for loop to iterate thru the dataset, use `innerHTML` to append `<option>`s to each.

```
var want = document.getElementById('want');
for(var i=mockData.profile.length; i--;)
    want.innerHTML += "<option>"+mockData.profile[i].gameWanted+"</option>";
```

Comment: Ouch! Setting the innerHTML like this cause the browser to do more work than it should, the elements do not need an ID in order to access them, and your for loop adds the elements in reverse order.

Comment: yeah i know. i could have put the html chunks in an array and then appended them with a join(), could have used insertadjacenthtml, could have selected byt tag name and interated thru all the select elements, could have used a class name instead.. could have ascended the loop instead of descended. just a quick example.

Answer (score 1):

I would perhaps suggest modifying your profile data structure:

```
"profile": [{
    "name": "Mario",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "California",
    "game": {"owned":["Grand Theft Auto 5 (PS4)"],
             "wanted":["Battlefield 4 (PS4)"]},
    "publishedAt": new Date()
}
```

```js
var mockData = {
"profile": [{
    "name": "Mario",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "California",
    "gameOwned": "Grand Theft Auto 5 (PS4)",
    "gameWanted": "Battlefield 4 (PS4)",
    "publishedAt": new Date()
}, {
    "name": "Colin",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "California",
    "gameOwned": "Battlefield 4 (PS4)",
    "gameWanted": "Grand Theft Auto 5 (PS4)",
    "publishedAt": new Date()
}],
"city": ["Los Angeles", "New York"],
    "game": ["Battlefield 4 (PS4)", "Grand Theft Auto 5 (PS4)"]
}

// The property names in the data that have associated select(s)
var fields = [ "city", "game" ];

function init() {
    // For each property
    fields.forEach( field => {
        // Find all the selects that are children of a list item with a class that starts with the field name
        document.querySelectorAll('li[class^='+field+'] select').forEach( select => {
            // Add a new option for every element in the field
            mockData[field].forEach( text => select.appendChild(new Option(text)))
        });
    });
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false );
```

```html
<body>
<li class="games-owned">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>What Game Do You Want To Trade?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="games-wanted">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>What Game Would You Like To Have?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="city">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>What City Do You Live In?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would give class for the different select elements

```
<li>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select class="select-game">
            <option value="" disabled selected>What Game Do You Want To Trade?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select class="select-game">
            <option value="" disabled selected>What Game Would You Like To Have?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select class="select-city">
            <option value="" disabled selected>What City Do You Live In?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
```

and then map the json to option elements -

```
var gameSelects = document.querySelectorAll('.select-game');

for (var i=0; i<gameSelects.length; i++) {
    mockData.game.map(function(game) {
        var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(game);
        option.appendChild(textnode);
        gameSelects[i].appendChild(option);
    })
}
```

and do the same for city select

Comment: got a typo... `gameSelects[i].appendChild(node);` node should be option

Comment: @naotor, thanks for the answer. Am i misunderstanding something? My console says node is not defined @ gameSelects[i].appendChild(node); Should I be passing in something to that arg?

Comment: @ColinAulds - read the other comments. i just pointed out the typo. `node` should actually be `option`